# Convert PDF to Text - Keep rows of table - Python

Tags: python, pdf, text, converters

I have tables in pdf documents that I want to convert to text.  I found the following code which converts the pdf to text.  However, when it converts, it does not keep the data in the correct rows.  It places everything in one long line of string.  Is there any way to preserve rows in a table when converting to text from PDF using Python?

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFDocument, PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter, process_pdf
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice, TagExtractor
from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.cmapdb import CMapDB
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf(path):

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp)
    fp.close()
    device.close()

    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str
```

Answer (score 1):

Pdfminer comes with text extraction tool called [pdf2txt.py](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/c7709045e9c9b19676b9df12656664f32b0963b1/tools/pdf2txt.py), which has the ability to analyze layouts. You can try using that, or study it to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

[A-PDF to Text](http://www.a-pdf.com/text/) convert better PDF with tables as other tools !